# Finding elements of specified orders in the group $\mathbb R^*$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In the group $\mathbb R^*$ can we find elements a and b such that $|a| = \infty$, $|b| = \infty$ and $ |ab| = 2$?

My attempt:
The group $\mathbb R^*$ means the set of real numbers with zero omitted, forms a group under multiplication.
1 is the identity.
And we can't find such a & b such that, $|a| = \infty$, $|b| = \infty$ and $ |ab| = 2$.

Am I right? If not, does there exist such $a$ & $b$ ? Any hint or suggestion ?

Comment: Do you know what $|ab| = 2$ means for $ab$?

Comment: The only element of order $2$ is $-1$. If $a$ has infinite order, what can you say about $-a$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring $ |ab|=2 $ means, $(ab)²=1$, i.e., $(ab)(ab)=1$, i.e., $(ab)^{-1}=ab$, i.e., $(b^{-1})(a^{-1})=ab$

Comment: There's no reason to do any of that.  If $x = ab$, then $x^2 = 1$.  Solve for $x$.  (e.g. remember that $\mathbb{R}$ is an integral domain, so subtract $1$ from both sides and factor)

Comment: What about $b = -\frac{1}{a}$ ?

Comment: @BrianMoehring it gives $ab =±1$, from this does there exist any real a & b? I can't figure this out!

Comment: @ArturoMagidin then -a has infinite order too! Am I right?

Comment: @Abezhiko then order of ab=1, but what about individual real a & b? I can't proceed!

Comment: Pick $a=2$ and $b=-1/2$. In fact any pair $a=x$ and $b=-1/x$ will work as long as $x\neq \pm 1$.

Comment: @freakish how $2^{\infty} = 1$ ?

Comment: @user954840 that is not what "$|a|=\infty$" means. The expression means "there is no $n>0$ such that $a^n=1$". Or equivalently: subgroup generated by $a$ is infinite.

Comment: @freakish thank you! It clears my doubt. I had misunderstood the meaning of $|a|=\infty$.

Comment: Now that you understand the situation, why not write up what you know and post it as an answer?

Comment: Use `$\infty$` for $\infty$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for ur motivation! But by the time I saw ur comment, 'freakish' has already written a beautiful solution!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are dealing with reals, so first let's answer the following question: what are possible orders of elements of $\mathbb{R}^*$? In order to avoid confusion with absolute value, I will use $o(x)$ to denote "order of $x$".

First, if $x>1$ then we can multiply both sides by $x$ to get $x^2>x$. And then by simple induction $x^n>1$ for any $n>0$, and so $o(x)=\infty$. Next, if $0<x<1$, then $o(x)=\infty$ as well, because $x^{-1}>1$ and $o(x)=o(x^{-1})$, which is a standard fact from group theory.

Finally, if $x<0$, $x\neq -1$, then $o(x)=\infty$ as well. Because otherwise, if $o(x)=m$ then $x^m=1$, and so $x^{2m}=1$, but $x^2>0$ and of course $x^2\neq 1$ because $x\neq -1$. And $x^2$ is of finite order, which contradicts previous paragraph.

What we showed is that $o(x)=\infty$ if $x\neq\pm 1$. Then of course $o(1)=1$ and $o(-1)=2$.

So pick any $x\in\mathbb{R}^*$ such that $x\neq\pm 1$. Then for $a=x$ and $b=-x^{-1}$ we have $o(a)=o(b)=\infty$ but $o(ab)=o(-1)=2$. And in fact $a,b$ have to be of such form for this to hold. A concrete example is $a=2$ and $b=-1/2$.